# _reactDom2.default.render is not a function

Tags: reactjs

consider the following react code

the main.js file is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Maincontainner from './maincontainner';

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <h1>News</h1>
        <Maincontainner/>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

and the component is:

```
import React from 'react';


export default class  Maincontainner extends React.Component{

    render() {
        console.log("I am here");
        return (<dev> Salman is here </dev>);
    }
}
```

the problem is, when i run the application, i face with following error in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _reactDom2.default.render is not a function
```

and here is the dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "react" : "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom" : "^0.14.7",
    "babel-cli": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0"


  }
```

Update: webpack.config.json

```
module.exports={

    entry: './js/main.js',
    output:{

        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.js?$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer:{


        port:3000
    }





};
```

I have also 1 .babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

Comment: What react version do you use?

Comment: "react" : "^0.14.7",
"react-dom" : "^0.14.7",

Comment: Using webpack + babel as the transpiler?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr yes i have added them to the question

Comment: What is your build script?

Comment: Provide please your webpack.config.js file too.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem, are you sure you didn't miss something in op?

Comment: I got this error with my project and it was resolved either by updating to latest React 15.1.0 or adding stage-0 to Babel, I'm not sure which.  If you post your entire project to GitHub or someplace else, I can help.

Comment: A little late here, but does importing just the methods you need help? Example: import { render } from 'react-dom';

Comment: As marcelino said, can you try this?

    import React from 'react';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';
    import Maincontainner from './maincontainner';
    
    render(
        <div>
            <h1>News</h1>
            <Maincontainner/>
        </div>,
        document.getElementById('content')
    );

Comment: I'm dealing with this right now, and none of the comment suggestions or answers work. What a strange issue...

Comment: To give some context. Logging the ReactDOM object shows an object with every DOM element tag as a key. Ie. { a: , body: , br: }

I tried logging React, and it looks correct, so it appears to only be an issue with react-dom

Comment: Ok, so I flushed some libraries and got rid of a lot of old code and im working from scratch.... im personally going to blame this on old code. Sorry I don't have an answer for anyone.

Comment: We just got this issue because we mistakenly did `import ReactDOM from 'react';` instead of `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can change something in your `Maincontainner` component.

1. Add it top: `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`
2. Change `render` to `ReactDOM.render`

Comment: Good find. That helped me. You can also import like: import { render } from 'react-dom'; and not have to change the code below.

Answer (score 16):

Initially, I was doing this.

```
import React from 'react-dom';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
```

And soon I realized what I was doing wrong and updated the above statements as follows.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: for transparency, the DIFFERENCE is the React importing from "react", not "react-dom". In my case I needed to change `import ReactDOM` to `import ReactDom`

Answer (score 1):

Update react and react-dom to "^15.2.1" works for me. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error when **update `react` version**. Maybe `_reactDom2.default.render is not a function` means because of `ReactDOM` doesn't have `render` function.

```
"dependencies": {
  "react" : "^0.14.7",
  "react-dom" : "^0.14.7"
}
```

to:

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^16.5.2",
  "react-dom": "^16.5.2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the tutorials I used this mentality and it seems to work well.

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class Pokemon extends Component{
    render() {
        const { pokemon, id } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="pokemon--species">..</div>
        );
    }
}


render(
    <div className="myDiv">Hello Electron!</div>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Hope this helps...Sometimes all of the dependencies, transpiling and configurations make this stuff a little overwhelming -_-

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wrote { import ReactDOM from 'react' }. Obviously, I should've used 'react-dom'

Answer (score 0):

in my case the issue was:

```
import render from "react-dom";
```

vs

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
```

I had to do it the second way, otherwise I got that error. would be interested to know why because they both seem valid

Answer (score 0):

Change the importing style to

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
     <App />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was I had this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
```

Changed it to this:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Answer (score 0):

For React latest version 18 try this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ReactDOM.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
          <App />
        </React.StrictMode>,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );
```

I had a problem with the word render, this solution helped me

```
import React from 'react-dom';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
```